# null check in where clause for running SQL Query

Tags: javascript, sql, database

let's say I have 2 tables D1 and D2. In D1, I have 'name' and 'id'. and in D2 I have 'name' and 'marks'.

Now I need to run a query where I have to check whether id is null or not and then return name and marks for that particular entry.

For now:

var query  = "SELECT D2.name as name FROM D1,D2 WHERE D1.name=D2.name and (here I need to put a null check.)

D1

```
  name | id
  A    | 12
  B    |
  C    | 11
  D    | 5
```

D2:

```
 name | marks
 B    | 24
 C    | 45
 E    | 33
```

Expected:

C   45

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: why you expect C45? you want that entries where the id is not null right? you expect B24, C45 and E 33 or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = "SELECT D2.name as Name, D2.marks as Marks FROM D1,D2 WHERE D1.name=D2.name and D1.id IS NOT NULL"
```

As you need name and marks in resultset. The result of the above query,

```
Name     Marks
---------------
C        45
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = "SELECT D2.name as name FROM D1,D2 WHERE D1.name=D2.name and D1.id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT D2.name as name FROM D1,D2 WHERE D1.name=D2.name and D1.id is not null

This works on mysql database. What is your dbms type?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query,

```
SELECT D2.name as name FROM D1 Join D2 On  D1.name=D2.name Where ISNull(D1.id, '')<>''
```